# Routing using modules

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Can somebody help me with routing in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R05VPzUm1hGrfLx4dH5P?p=preview)? I want to navigate to `RegistrationComponent`.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: May I know why this title is better than previous one & why you removed plunker tag

Comment: 1. Because you should include tags as tags, not in the title. 2. Because although you've hosted the code example on Plunker (which you shouldn't do, see [mcve]) it's not actually part of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually that's what I'm trying to do. I want to run that example on plunker.

Comment: I've posted an answer below, but like the people before me are saying, you should really include a better description of what the problem is, what you've tried to fix it and include some code snippets in the question itself as opposed to merely linking to plnkr.

Comment: Thanks !! I'll certainly try to incorporate other details while asking questions